# adding data in fields of a single document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this data:

```
_id : 1
status:1, 
name:"name",
details:
{ 
  crm:115, 
  webs: 
    { tag:"blog" , url:"http://..."}, 
  contacts:
    {
      _id:1,
      name:"me", 
      phones:
        { tag:"home", number:"123..." },
        {tag:"mobile", number:"123456789"}
    }
}
```

I want one more entry in "phones" with `{tag:office", number:"9823..."}`

What would be the command/query for that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, can you clarify your question?

Comment: Please do not refer to another question. Create a seperate, stand-alone question with a clear question, a clear schema and the problem you are unable to solve. Thanks ;)

Comment: Here is it, the above mentioned is my final question, sorry for the previous one. :)

Comment: Please show the code that you've tried. It looks like you want phones to be an array, so, you'd need to use `$push`: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/

Comment: db.abcd.update(
    {
        _id : 1
    },
    
    {
        $push:
             {details:
                {
                    contacts:
                    {
                        phones:
                        {
                            tag:"office",
                            rname:"9823"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
      }
);

Answer (score 2):

You can easily push this into the array with the following query (I had to modify the JSON you pasted, as it was not valid a little):

```js
db.collection.drop();
db.collection.insert( {
    _id : 1,
    status: 1, 
    name: "name",
    details: { 
        crm:115, 
          webs: {
            tag:"blog",
            url:"http://..."
        }, 
        contacts: {
            _id: 1,
            name: "me", 
            phones: [
                { tag: "home", number: "123..." },
                { tag:"mobile", number:"123456789" }
            ]
        }
    }
} );

db.collection.update(
    { _id: 1 },
    { $push : { 'details.contacts.phones' : {  tag:"office", rname:"9823" } } }
);

db.collection.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "details" : {
    "contacts" : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "me",
        "phones" : [
            {
                "tag" : "home",
                "number" : "123..."
            },
            {
                "tag" : "mobile",
                "number" : "123456789"
            },
            {
                "tag" : "office",
                "rname" : "9823"
            }
        ]
        },
        "crm" : 115,
        "webs" : {
        "tag" : "blog",
        "url" : "http://..."
        }
    },
    "name" : "name",
    "status" : 1
}
```

Comment: When I do so I get error "Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array" :(

Comment: I actually tested with the document that you showed above. I've updated my example with the insert and find+results too.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much for that, but suppose if I want to add new entry in contacts say, {_id:2,name:"hitesh"}.. Then, for that the following doesn't work and why? db.collection.update(
    { _id: 1 },
    { $push : { 'details.contacts' : {  _id:2, name:"hitesh" } } }
);

Comment: That's because contacts is not an array, but just a simple document. It needs to be an array if you want to push into it. However, if you turn that into an array, then the original push to add a phone number no longer works. You can only have one of them to work. In your case, you probably want to split out contacts+phone into a different collection with a link back to the main document.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `$push` operator must refer to the array to be updated.  So when the array field is embedded in other documents you need to use dot notation like this:

```js
db.abcd.update({_id: 1}, 
    {$push: {"details.contacts.phones": {tag:"office", rname:"9823"}}});
```

Comment: Thats ok with arrays, but I haven't used arrays, so how do I query to push data in "phones", is there any other way ?

Comment: @Hitesh Ok, I assumed `phones` was an array as what you show isn't a valid doc.  Can you fix `phones` in your example doc to show what you mean?

Comment: When I do so I get error "Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array" :(